# Isometry between punctured sphere and punctured triangle?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, metric-spaces

---

**Setup:**

Let $C_n$ be a closed $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $r \in (0,R)$ where $R$ is the distance any one of the vertices $\{v_1,\cdots , v_{n+1}\}$ of $C_n$ to the centroid $\frac{v_1+ \cdots v_{n+1}}{n+1}\in C_n$.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way or removing a connected open set $A$ from the interior of $C_n$ such that for every $c \in \partial C_n$
$$
r= d(\partial A, c) \left(\triangleq \inf_{a \in \partial A}d(a,c)\right)?
$$

Comment: Do you assume the simplex to be regular?

Comment: consider the inscribed sphere

Comment: Yes i do... also the sphere does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such $A$. Let $c$ be a point from the boundary of $C_n$ that belongs to an intersection of at least two distinct facets $F_1, F_2$ (so $c$ is in a face of dimension at most $n-2$). In the plane, $c$ is a vertex of the triangle $C_2$.

Since the simplex is regular, the angle between any two of its facets is sharp ( smaller than $\pi/2$). In particular, if $x$ is a point in $C_n$ at distance $r+\varepsilon$ from $c$, then both $d(F_1,x)$ and $d(F_2,x)$ are strictly smaller than $(r+\varepsilon)/\sqrt{2}$.